# DDS DomainParticipantFactory Error CORBA

Tags: c++, ubuntu, data-distribution-service

I'm trying to create a program to test Opensplice DDS. However I'm facing some problems for which I've been stuck for quite a long time.

When I try to create a `DomainParticipantFactory` I got an error which says `CORBA:NO_IMPLEMENT`. The program works if I don't create the `DomainParticipant` so I thought  that the problem lays there.

```
DDS::DomainParticipantFactory_var dpf = DDS:DomainParticipantFactory::get_instance();
// get_instance() causes the crash.
```

Would somebody ever faced such a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I've found my solution, I post here in case anyone gets it.

The problem was a misbehavior due to overlapping librairies.

I was linkings CCPP and SACPP together. That made some kind of explosive mix that the system didn't like much.

So don't link the wrong library. Depending if you use CORBA system or not, choose carefully.

Comment: That's right, the CCPP libraries should only be used in applications that need to cohabitate with CORBA.